# Android and linked libraries

Tags: android, shared-libraries, dalvik

Maybe the question can sound silly for the java users. Sorry, i'm a noob.

I'm wondering how libraries are loaded during runtime in an `Android` system.

Let's say i have a super simple android app that only call a function located in `javax.net.ssl` package.

The jar (dex) containing `javax.net.ssl` stuff will be inserted into the apk (turning it into a static library)? 
Or during the runtime, the `Dalvik VM` will link to the jar (or dex) file installed on the android machine? 
Or just the `Dalvik VM` was compiled to contain every javax include itself?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are in effect dynamically linked at runtime by loading additional optimized dex code stored on the device.

In actuality for many components this happens once at system startup, with the process and virtual machine contained therein that becomes each application inheriting read only access to a shared copy already in memory.

Native libraries work about the same way only the linkage happens below the level of the virtual machine, in the process itself.

Comment: So... are you telling me that a `android.jar` library exists on every phone and it will be loaded by the VM everytime the phone boot?

Comment: Effectively yes, but its not called that.  It has the real implementations, while android.jar in the sdk has opaque fakes to guide the toolchain.

Comment: This real implementation is embedded into dalvik compiled code? Or is it loaded from a file during the Dalvik startup phase? I'm asking this because i have a doubt. If the latter file exists, what if I can find that and modify it in a malicious way? (for example, i can change javax.net.ssl routines and make them dump DECRYPTED data of SSL connections)

Comment: It's several files, most of which are loaded at zygote's startup long before anything having to do with your app or a process running under your app's user id occurs.  If you had root and a writable system partition, you could indeed change this - because at that point, you transcend the security model (you could change _anything_ for which you could come up with a functionally close replacement, including the dvm, or if you can write elsewhere the kernel, etc).  But without root or a comparable bug, you can't change the system library files.

Comment: +1 & accepted answer ;). I got a last question. Do you know where this files are located on the phone?

Comment: Usually a lot of the native libs are in /system/lib while a lot of the java components are in /system/framework but that is implementation specific detail which could change at any point or on any device.